# Two identical CSS files, one modified, replace only the altered styles, is that possible?

Tags: css

I have two files where I edited one and left the other just for reference.
However I screwed some codes on the file I'm editing and since its a huge file, I don't know where I made the error or even if it have more errors. It was not altered I just deleted it.

I want to know if there is a program, plugin, script, something that I can insert the two files and override only the parameters of the classes that was edited (the class names wasn't altered).

I know I should have used GIT and all but I didn't. Lesson learned.

Appreciate any help. I'm using SublimeText.

Comment: What you want is a diff tool. If you're on a Mac, I suggest http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com Otherwise, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools

Comment: As this question is to recommend a tool or library, it is off topic for [SO].

Comment: Thank you guys for the answer. Didn't know about diff. @zzzzBov I don't think it is off topic and I didn't wanted recommendations at first. The question was not "which is best" but to know if a tool exists. Thank you for your down vote.

Comment: @audaz802, please review the help pages. ["Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Sublimerge can do it for you in your editor:
http://www.sublimerge.com/

Comment: Ok @zzzzBov you're right. Fact that I don't know how to be helped without asking this way since Google returned no relevant matches. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Jani Hyytiäinen THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Is it possible is an easy yes or no question. Try "Two identical CSS files, one modified, replace only the altered styles, is that possible, and if so, how?" Ask better questions and you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a Unix-like OS, or you have Cygwyn installed you can use diff and patch to do this.

```
$ diff -u old.css new.css > changes.diff
$ patch < changes.diff
```